# Apache forward HTTPS -> HTTPS different domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, https

I have a question about url rewriting and .htaccess files.

I am trying to accomplish the following:
Redirect Example.co.uk -> New.com/en-gb/

This works fine except when the user navigates to the HTTPS version of the old domain:
https://example.co.uk (or https://www.example.co.uk)

How do I properly forward traffic from https://example.co.uk -> https://new.com/en-gb/ ?

I have tried many different rewrite rules I found online but none of them seem to work and accomplish a complete redirect.

Current .htaccess file:

```
Redirect 301 / https://new.com/en-gb/
```

---

#### Solved

Solved thanks to Dusan Bajic:
The solution was to create a new free Lets Encrypt certificate for the old domain and place the .htaccess file in both Public_html & Private_html.

All redirects now work as expected!

Comment: Can you describe what exactly happens when the redirect does not work?

Comment: I arrive on the following page:
Welcome to example.co.uk
To change this page, upload a new index.html to your private_html folder

Comment: Did old https url work before adding Redirect to .htaccess?

Comment: No we just bought the domain name to prevent confusion. There was never a site on it. It should be possible to redirect https://example.co.uk -> https://new.com/en-gb/ right?

Comment: Yes, it should. Do you have access to apache .conf files (for "old" site), or is this some shared webhosting?

Comment: We are on a shared host and I don't think I have access. Any other suggestions?

Comment: If you place simple index.html next to .htaccess, will `https://example.co.uk/index.html` open it successfully ?

Comment: I just tried it and it worked. However the index.html file required to be placed in private_html and not public_html. But it did work! What do you suggest as a next step?

Comment: place .htaccess there?

Comment: You are a genius. Thanks for your suggestions and help. I will add the solution to my question. Thanks again

Comment: Also, do you have separate webhosting for example.co.uk and new.com?

Comment: No same webhost. The solution was to get a new Lets Encrypt certificate for the old website and include the .htaccess in the private_html folder.

Comment: Please move the solution to an answer of its own.